# What do you call a UI element which expands an area of fields in a window?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, controls, wpf-controls

I am trying to make UI element which expands/collapses an area of fields in a window. I need it specifically for a WPF project.
As an example take the element in the link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDgNl.png

Pushing the down button expands the area to include more fields as in the example below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN6bO.png

Does this kind of UI element have a name? I don't really know what to google to see whether it has been done before.

Comment: Oh so simple. Cool I'll check out Expanders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/expander-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) control:

```
<Expander>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>put your controls to be expanded/collapsed here...</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

Comment: Does this provide support for showing some fields before expanding/after collapsing? Or would that be a custom control?

Comment: The contents are shown when the `Expander` is expanded. You can set the `IsExpanded` property to `true` to expand it by default.

Comment: Yes ok. I think this will do, but it was not quite the functionality I was thinking. I wanted it to be collapsed by default, but showing some fields. Think of it more like a control which groups a collection of ui elements in the window, with an IsCollapsed/IsShown attribute on the items. 

It might not even be a thing, which is fine. I'm going to leave the question hanging for a bit to see if anyone else have an input

Comment: or you could just leave the always shown fields outside of the expander...

Comment: Yes I could... That's probably also what mm8 was thinking